# Projecting a Circle onto the x-y plane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

Essentially, this boils down to finding the equation of an ellipse formed by slicing a cone at a random angle. Now let me explain more: I have an equation for a cone which is at a specific angle (say 54 degrees above the x-y plane). I want to find the ellipse formed from it onto the x-y plane. I have the equation of the circle sliced perpendicular to the cone axis at the specific point, however, I don't know where to go from there. How can I find the projection of this circle onto the x-y plane?

I'm not sure if I'm right, but shouldn't this ellipse have a longer major axis than the original circle's diameter?

Although I saw a similar thread, it wasn't super helpful, for I ran into some problems with it. The circle became an ellipse, but the major axis stayed the same as the circle's original diameter.

Thanks for any help!

Edit: I started with a cone whose equation was:

$\frac{1}{217.5^2}(z+6.802)^2=x^2+y^2$

I then changed this into a vector function:

$<x\space,\space y\space,\space217.5\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-6.802>$

Next, I rotated the cone 54° up about $x=0$ and 214.5° around $z'=0$.

As you can imagine, this vector became ugly as sin.

Comment: Can't you just substitute $z=0$ into the original equation of the cone?

Comment: I have the cone defined parametrically, and when I set the z component of that vector =0, I get the equation of the circle in the x'-y' plane I believe. When I plug that circle into desmos, its a perfect circle. Maybe I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: My equation for the cone was of the form z^2=x^2+y^2.  Then I made it into <x,y,sqrt(x^2+y^2)>. I then plugged that formula into a transformation matrix. Now it's a very ugly vector function. Is there anything I can do with that to solve it back into an equation with z?

Comment: If the equation of the cone is $x^2+y^2=z^2,$ then the intersection with the $xy$-plane is $(0,0,0)$.  This doesn't seem to gibe with your previous comment about parametric equations.  Put all the details you can **into the body of the question**, not the comments.